# Groovy: LinkedHashMap value in In quotation marks

Tags: groovy, linkedhashmap

I'm new in Groovy. 
I make map in loop like this `[(nodeRootName): (value)]`

And after all conversions conert it in JSON:
`def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( map )`
And this crash, because in map value not valid. 
Map like as `[nsiKTRUs:[[position:[data:[[code:01.11.11.111-00001], [version:1], [inclusionDate:2018-06-16T05:53:14+04:00]...`
How I can put in quotation marks `value`?
I try

```
String value = ""
value = Node.text()
map = [(nodeRootName): (value)]
```

And 
`map = [(nodeRootName): ("\"" + ${value} + "\"")]`
and `map = [(nodeRootName): ("${value.toString()}")]`
But map all the same `[nsiKTRUs:[[position:[data:[[code:01.11.11.111-00001], [version:1], [inclusionDate:2018-06-16T05:53:14+04:00]...`

Comment: Could you please provide the full example, that shows the problem and gives the error?  What is `Node`, what is `nodeRootName`, ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're doing, but it looks like your question is essentially just "How can I put quotation marks in a String value".

If that is the case, you can escape them (same as Java):

```
String value = "Hello \"world\"."
```

Or you can triple-quote the string:

```
String value = """Hello "world"."""
```

That said, none of this seems to be related to a map or JSON parsing so maybe you're asking something entirely different.  If that's the case, please clarify.

Comment: My full question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039371/apache-nifi-1-6-crash-groovy-script

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
map = [(nodeRootName): ("${value.toString()}")]
```

You can do this:

```
map = [(nodeRootName): "\"${value}\""]
```

Example:

```
groovy:000> nodeRootName = 'some root name'
===> some root name
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> value = 'some value'
===> some value
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> map = [(nodeRootName): ("${value.toString()}")]
===> [some root name:some value]
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> map = [(nodeRootName): "\"${value}\""]
===> [some root name:"some value"]
```